# WRAP_CONTENT of listview is not working

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` which contains list of app icons which are added in `ListView` during runtime process. I want my `ListView` width to be `WRAP_CONTENT`. But `WRAP_CONTENT` doesn't work and from some resource I have heard that `WRAP_CONTENT` didn't work try using `MATCH_PARENT`. When I tried it cover up the whole screen. I am using `ListView` in service class so I had made it programmatically like this:

First of all I created a simple Linear layout like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams listParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
listLinear.setLayoutParams(listParam);  //listLinear is my linearLayout on Listview is implemented.
listView.setLayoutParams(listParam);
listLinear.addView(listView);
```

here width of `LinearLayout` is set as 80 because `WRAP_CONTENT` is not working so I adjusted its width size by passing a value.I am testing this in my **Moto e(1st gen)** whose screen inch is **4.3 inch**. But when I test it in device which has screen inch as **5 inch** it just resize the content inside the `ListView` into small, I have to set layout width as 100 then only it looks perfect.

So how can I enable `WRAP_CONTENT` of `ListView` so that it does the work automatically?

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: dont try to set the width of listview,instead try to modify the view that you are inflating in your listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never give dimensions in `pixels` like **80** or **100**. As device changes resolution changes so it will look different on different devices. Better use following function to convert your dimension from `density independent pixel(dp)` to equivalent `pixels` according to each device's `density`.

So you can use `DimensionUtils.dpToPx(80)` instead of **80**.

```
public final class DimensionUtils {

    private static boolean isInitialised = false;
    private static float pixelsPerOneDp;

    // Suppress default constructor for noninstantiability.
    private DimensionUtils() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    private static void initialise(View view) {
        pixelsPerOneDp = view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 160f;
        isInitialised = true;
    }

    public static float pxToDp(View view, float px) {
        if (!isInitialised) {
            initialise(view);
        }

        return px / pixelsPerOneDp;
    }

    public static float dpToPx(View view, float dp) {
        if (!isInitialised) {
            initialise(view);
        }

        return dp * pixelsPerOneDp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I will try it:)